# Difference between WaitAll and Wait

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, dynamics-crm-2011

I have developed an ASP.NET page that retrieved data from CRM 2011.
There are several invocations and the page takes several seconds to load.

I thought I might use some parallelism to speed things up.

This is the code:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];

tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
{

    RetrieveAttributeRequest retrieveFreightTerm = new RetrieveAttributeRequest { };
    retrieveFreightTerm.EntityLogicalName = "account";
    retrieveFreightTerm.LogicalName = "address1_freighttermscode";

    retrieveFreightTerm.MetadataId = Guid.Empty;
    retrieveFreightTerm.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;

    RetrieveAttributeResponse retrieveFrieghtTermResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)Service.Execute(retrieveFreightTerm);

    PicklistAttributeMetadata retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)retrieveFrieghtTermResponse.AttributeMetadata;


    OptionMetadata[] optionlist = retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options.ToArray();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    foreach (OptionMetadata oMD in optionlist)
    {
        FreightTermDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(oMD.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label, oMD.Value.ToString()));

    }
});
```

after the tasks I use

```
Task.WaitAll();
```

I have been debugging the code and the data is retrieved, but the dropdown lists are empty anyway.

Changing the

```
Task.WaitAll();
```

to

```
tasks[0].Wait(2000);
tasks[1].Wait(2000);
tasks[2].Wait(2000);
tasks[3].Wait(2000);
```

makes the code to work (I have 4 tasks). What is the difference between the two options?

Comment: Possibly related to your problem is that the CRM service proxy classes are not threadsafe. You'll need to make sure that each task (or at least each thread) has its own instance of the organisation and/or metadata service, rather than have all of them use `Service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `tasks` array to `WaitAll()` method:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The difference between `WaitAll()` and `Wait()` is that `Wait()` is used to await completion of a specific task (the instance on which `Wait()` is called) and `WaitAll()` awaits completion of *all* the tasks given as parameter.

Again, in order for `WaitAll()` to work, you need to pass the actual tasks you're awaiting on.

Comment: @Stijn, `WaitAll()` is defined as `Task.WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)` thus it can be called without a parameter.

Comment: Well spotted. I'm surprised it doesn't throw if you don't pass it any tasks.